# How to find git repository in file explorer from github

Tags: git, github, command-line, command-prompt

I have a github repository created. I've done this before but somehow I have forgotten and have no clue of doing this, nothing seems to work.

The example name of the repo: Ex1

I do the following(the reccomended) in Admin/Desktop:

```
echo "# Ex1" >> README.md
git init
git add README.md
git commit -m "first commit"
git branch -M main
git remote add origin https://github.com/myname/Ex1.git
git push -u origin main
```

Then, I can't seem to open the file in file explorer, once I've created it like that, which I think is possible issue.

Though, I then clone the git repository onto my computer, add files into it via like ctrl c ctrl v of files in file explorer itself, but when doing "git push origin main" nothing happens in github, leading me to believe I wasnt supossed to git clone, and was instead somehow supposed to find the file itself.

Is there some command or some way to find the file once I init it? (Show hidden files is alr enabled, still nowhere to be found though)

Comment: Your post reads like you're using the terms "git" and "github" interchangeably. You are aware that they are not the same thing?

Comment: _"Then, I can't seem to open the file in file explorer"_ - **what file** are you referring to? And what do you mean "can't seem to open"... do you get an error message? You know that Windows doesn't come with a Markdown editor, right?

Comment: In respons eto initial prompt, yep, git and github I believe were used as intended. And to pt 2, the file is whatever the result is of the segment of git commands in the post. And I can't seem to open it because I dont know how or even if there is something to open.

My ultimate goal is just to be able to have the folder in file explorer that I can edit directly not through terminal and then when im done just do "git push origin main"

Comment: ...it looks like you're turning your actual Desktop folder into a git repo instead of a subdirectory? You won't want to do that.

Comment: That just depends in which folder you run those commands. `git init` creates a repository in the current working directory. That's also where you'll find README.md and as long as you run git commands from that same folder, what you want is exactly how git always works.

Comment: Found out in the meantime?
If not, again: 
"Then, I can't seem to open the file in file explorer, once I've created it like that"

Which file?
Any screenshots?
What are you even trying to "open", and how?
Getting any error messages?

Answer (score 0):

> My ultimate goal is just to be able to have the folder in file explorer that I can edit directly not through terminal and then when im done just do "git push origin main"

That should be possible through a text editor like VSCode which lets you add, commit and push from its Git view.

Note that any GitHub repository can be edited directly from the web through the key <kbd>.</kbd> (dot): that clones the repository in a [GitHub Codespace](https://github.com/features/codespaces).